# Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! in Entity, line: 1049 in

Tags: php, api

I am using auto post social site API from [here](https://code.google.com/p/socials-auto-poster/). It gives the following error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate
>   encoding ! in Entity, line: 1049 in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\fb\SocialAutoPoster\api\Googleplus.php on line 82